# Как отправить уведомления в верхней части экрана чата без нажатия на callback кнопку?

Tags: python, aiogram

Кейс: нужно, отправляя сообщения от 1 пользователя, получать у другого в виде всплывающих уведомлений[image: введите сюда описание изображения].
Нашел только `bot.answer_callback_query()`, но там требуется `callback_query_id=callback.id`.
который не понятно как сгенерировать.
Буду рад любой подсказке.
Главная задача: принудительно вызвать всплывающие уведомление у определенного пользователя не нажимая на кнопки.
спасибо!

Comment: Никак... Это особенность колбеков

Comment: answer_callback_query это бот отправляет это самое сообщение, но чаще юзается чтобы убрать иконку часиков возле инлайн кнопки

Answer (score 0):

То что вы имеете ввиду вызывается очень просто

```
await query.answer('некое уведомление')
```

Работает только в callback_query_handler

Comment: благодарю за ваш ответ. На сколько я понял, вы говорите об обычном CallbackQuery.answer - который требует наличия CallbackQuery(нажатия на клавишу).Проблема заключается в том, что мой **handler** принимает `async def chat_client_operator(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):` и просто отправляет сообщения `await bot.send_message(data['operator_id'], message.text)` но при определенных условиях я хочу отправлять вместо сообщений-уведомления определенному пользователю. Возможно, вы знаете как сгенерировать CallbackQuery без нажатия на кнопу?